# RobotLegs - Mediator for main application class

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, model-view-controller, robotlegs

I'm trying to mediate the main application class ( the 'Document class' of a Flash *.fla project)

I have this on the Application Context startup():

> ...
>   mediatorMap.mapView(MyApplication,MyApplicationMediator);
>   mediatorMap.createMediator(contextView);

The MyApplicationMediator:

> public class MyApplicationMediator
>   extends Mediator {
>   [Inject]
>   public var view:MyApplication;
>   override public
>   function onRegister():void {
>   trace("I am registered!");
>   }

So onRegister() gets called, but view is null. Also when I try to add the eventListeners I get a null reference error.

Comment: Nevermind. I just forgot to check the option 'Export SWC' in publish settings. That is needed in order to the annotations (metadata) work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is *generally* a result of compiling robotlegs from source and not having keep-as3-metadata +=Inject as a compiler option.

I think that your createMediator call is superfluous. The contextView is a "special" case in that it is already added to the stage so by default when the mediator is set via mapView it gets created automatically.

This [Common Problems](https://github.com/robotlegs/robotlegs-framework/wiki/common-problems#no-injection) section of the wiki is a pretty decent resource.